# Importing GeoTiff or IMG formats with Ironpython

Tags: geotiff-tiff, import

[McNeel Rhino 5](https://www.rhino3d.com/) application is using IronPython 2.7, and this is the application to which I would like to import either a GeoTiff or .img formats.

I googled a bit a found a couple of python modules, which are able to do this, but I couldn't find any information about IronPython ones.

Any recommendations on how could this be done in IronPython?
I found out that I could use some [gdal.dll](http://www.gdal.org/) library which contains functionalities for importing both upper formats, but this library is 64 bit only. I need 32 bit one.